# Conjugate classes and solvable groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Assume that G is a finite solvable group. Is there always a non-trivial element g in G such that the conjugacy class of g generates a commutative subgroup of G? Why?

Comment: Are you familiar with the structure of a minimal normal subgroup of a solvable group?

Comment: Actually, even simpler: Consider the smallest non-trivial term in the derived series.

Comment: Either way, any nontrivial solvable group has a nontrivial abelian normal subgroup. You don't need to assume that $G$ is finite. (But you do need to assume that $G$ is nontrivial!)

Comment: I understand that taking the derived series you get groups $G,G_1,\ldots,G_k,G_{k+1}={e}$ such that each $G_{i+1}$ is normal in $G_i$. So, $G_k$ is certainly abelian, but how can I get an element $g\in G$ such that the subgroup $\langle g^G\rangle$ is commutative?

Comment: If $G_k$ were normal in $G$ then the conclusion follows, but I don't think this is always the case.

Comment: If you take the derived series, then the subgroups are indeed normal.

Comment: So, are you saying that $G_i$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$?

Comment: That depends on what your $G_i$ is (the terms in the derived series are usually either denoted by $G'$, $G''$ and so on or $G^{(i)}$).

Comment: But they are definitely the terms of the derived series. In my case, $G_i=G^{(i)}$.

Comment: Is it always true that $G^{(i)}$ is a normal subgroup in $G$?

Comment: Yes. Note that in fact each $G^{(i)}$ is characteristic in $G^{(i-1)}$ (this is easy to show). Thus each is also characteristic (and particularly, normal) in $G = G^{(0)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Once you know that all subgroups in the derived series of $G$ are normal in $G$, it is enough to take any non-trivial element in the smallest non-trivial group of the derived series. This is basically Tobias Kildetoft answer, but I didn't know how to put her comment as the answer of the question.